# Log in error after upgrade to 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, upgrade, ssh

I just updated my file server from 16.04 to 18.04 LTS and I am now getting the following error when I log into the server:

Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings

I checked my internet connection and it works.  In fact the error is consistent whether I login at the console or with an SSH connection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

As noted, this is a known bug that has now been fixed. You can fix this with the following:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available 
sudo /etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391641&p=13779586#post13779586

> This bug was reported and just fixed. However, it looks like it is merged into the 18.10 branch.